# AdonisJS .join for Many to Many relation

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, adonis.js

I have 3 tables, Actors, Matters and a pivot table Actor_Matter with pivot columns "relation" and "primary". I want to query to get all Matters and join the actor where the relation and primary conditions of 'client' and 'true' are met. The reason for the join is that I need to be able to orderBy the client name, which only appears possible if the table is joined.

My head is very confused as to how to do this :P I feel like I should be able to just .join using the existing relationship defined in the model but the .join seems to be model ignorant so I have to effectively write an SQL query. What I have now is listed in the controller code below. It works, but it doesn't return all matters, only those with matching primary client.

There's some combination of joins I need to do to return ALL matters, I guess with null value for client_name.

Actor Model:

```
@manyToMany(() => Matter, {
pivotTable: 'actor_matter',
pivotColumns: ['relation', 'primary_actor'],
})
public matters: ManyToMany<typeof Matter>
```

Matter Model:

```
 //relationships
@manyToMany(() => Actor, {
pivotTable: 'actor_matter',
pivotColumns: ['relation', 'primary_actor', 'actor_reference'],
})
public actors: ManyToMany<typeof Actor>

@manyToMany(() => Actor, {
pivotTable: 'actor_matter',
pivotColumns: ['relation', 'primary_actor'],
onQuery: (query) => {
  query.wherePivot('relation', 'client').wherePivot('primary_actor', true)
},
})
public client: ManyToMany<typeof Actor>
```

Controller:

```
const matters = await Matter.query()
    .preload('client')
    .preload('owner')

     //Join actors where relation is client and primary_actor is true.
    .leftJoin('actor_matter', 'matters.id', 'actor_matter.matter_id')
    .join('actors', (query) => {
      query
        .on('actor_matter.actor_id', 'actors.id')
        .andOnVal('actor_matter.relation', '=', 'client')
        .andOnVal('actor_matter.primary_actor', '=', true)
    })
    .select('actors.name as client_name', 'actors.id as client_id')

    .select('matters.*')
    .orderBy(sortParams.sortField, sortParams.sortOrder === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc')
    .paginate(page, perPage)

    .select('matters.*')
    .orderBy(sortParams.sortField, sortParams.sortOrder === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc')
    .paginate(page, perPage)
```